# Which spelling is correct? Theatre or Theater?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spelling

Theatre or theater - which word is correct for using in GB and US? I faced with both and also heard the opinion that "theatre" is not used in US, although it's definitely not true.

Comment: Please consider waiting a couple days before accepting an answer.  You might get one that addresses both AmE and BrE spelling properly.  At the moment you've accepted an answer that only describes AmE spelling, even though your question asks about both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To distinguish between American and British spelling](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131287/to-distinguish-between-american-and-british-spelling)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Although I was interested in a detailed answer, I have a special interest in AmE. But your сomment is wise in general, I got it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the U.S.:

- "Theater" is used in ordinary writing.
- "Theatre" is sometimes used in the names of venues or arts groups that want to seem "high class" or "old fashioned".

These usages are similar to "the", "old", and "shop", as opposed to "ye", "olde", and "shoppe".

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries say that "***theater***" is *US spelling* while "***theatre***" is *UK spelling*. However, according to some dictionaries "***theatre***" is now equally acceptable in the US.

> The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) says the “*The earliest recorded English forms, c1380, are **theatre** and **teatre**; from c1550 to 1700, or later, the prevalent spelling was **theater** (so in Dictionaries from Cawdrey to Kersey), but **theatre** in Holland, Milton, Fuller, Dryden, Addison, Pope; Bailey 1721 has both, ‘**Theatre**, **Theater**’: and between 1720 and 1750, **theater** was dropped in Britain, but has been retained or (?) revived in U.S.*”

- According to the [**British National Corpu**s](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=58325257) the word ***theatre*** is more common in the **UK**.
- According to the [**Corpus of Contemporary American English**](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) the word ***theater*** is more common in the **US**.

> In **British English**, some words from French, Latin or Greek end with a consonant followed by an unstressed **-re** *(pronounced (non-rhotic accent)* /**ə(ɹ)**/ or *(rhotic accent)* **/ɚ/**). In **American English**, most of these words have the ending **-er**. The difference is most common for words ending **-bre** or **-tre**: British spellings *calibre, centre, fibre, goitre, litre, lustre, manoeuvre, meagre, metre, mitre, nitre, ochre, reconnoitre, sabre, saltpetre, sepulchre, sombre, spectre, theatre* (see exceptions) and *titre* all have **-er** in American spelling.

[**Wikipedia - American and British English spelling differences**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-re.2C_-er)

In the US it's also common among some folks to refer to the building as "**theater**" and to the act as "**theatre**". However, not everyone follows such practice, and many exclusively use the American spelling. "**Theatre**" often appears in the proper names of American theaters, for example: *the American Ballet Theatre, the Muncie Civic Theatre, and the Genessee Theatre*. When referring to these buildings by the common noun "**theater**" is the usual spelling.

See: [**“Theater” vs. “Theatre” in American English**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202651/theater-vs-theatre-in-american-english)

Comment: You will *see* both in the United States, but in your own writing it's best to use **theater**.

Comment: @Andrew I agree both can be seen.

Comment: I faced with "theatre" even in the Department of Theatre of UCSB

Comment: In British English it is still more common to use theatre not the American English spelling of theater. @ Weather Vane this is an English site, and there are several versions of it in the modern world American, British, as just two of them, there are for example Australian and India as well.

Comment: As you can see if you check the [British National Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=58325257), *theater* is not more common than *theatre* in BrE spelling.

Comment: I would always used the correct British spelling of theatre, and as sailplane has shown theatre is more common in the Britiish National Corpus. Unless you have proof that theater is more common I would stand by my statement.